# ckeditor - onshow overiding custom definition

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

when using the ckeditor link dialog, I have custom code for some extra options. I would also like to grab the selected text to use - so I have called:

```
selectedContents = CKEDITOR.instances['my_editor'].getSelection().getSelectedText();
```

I want this to happen when the dialog is loaded. So I wrote an "onShow()" handler function... but that messes up the customizations that I have made to the dialog. I'm guessing that my onShow is grabbing the normal process for that event - how can I continue with the normal processing at that point?

```
dialogDefinition.onShow = function(evt) 
{
  contents = CKEDITOR.instances['my_editor'].getSelection().getSelectedText();

  // now here, continue as you were...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I still have some issues, but the answer to this question is to grab the existing "onShow" handler before overwriting it. Use a global, then it can be called within the new handler:

```
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
var oldOnShow = dialogDefinition.onShow;


dialogDefinition.onShow = function(evt) {
    // do some stuff
    // do some more stuff

    // call old function
    oldOnShow();
}
```

Comment: yuur propositon looks like solution. but not for my problem v4.5.3;
first time calling dialog - clear console; next shows error:
Uncaught TypeError: this.getParentEditor is not a function(…)

all what I do: `
var oldOnShow = dialogDefinition.onShow;

                console.log(oldOnShow);

                dialogDefinition.onShow = function () {

                    console.log('here');

                    oldOnShow();
}`

Comment: I am overriding the Link dialog. When I invoke 'onShow' as you indicate, I take an error... however the previous post `oldOnShow.call(this, arguments);' works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on Andy Wallace code:

```
var oldOnShow = dialogDefinition.onShow;
var newOnShow = function () { 
//your code 
}
```

and then:

```
dialogDefinition.onShow = function(){

                    oldOnShow.call(this, arguments);
                    newOnShow.call(this, arguments);

                }
```

It helps me!

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax is:

```
/* if new picture, then open the Upload tab */
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var dialog = dialogDefinition.dialog;
    if (dialogName == 'image2') {
        dialogDefinition.onShow = CKEDITOR.tools.override(dialogDefinition.onShow, function(original) { 
            return function() {
                original.call(this);
                CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout( function() {
                    if (dialog.getContentElement('info', 'src').getValue() == '') {
                        dialog.selectPage('Upload');
                    }
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```